# Cue Card program in python

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have asked a similar question to this before but I can never seem to get a solution that works properly (most likely down to my lack of programming knowledge)

I am trying to create a "cue card" system. Adding cards to a program, storing them in certain decks and then having these decks output their cards when asked to. I am using Tkinter as my GUI for this. So far this is my code;

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

question_list = []
topic_list = []
data = defaultdict(list)

x = 5
while x > 0:
    question = input("what is your question?")
    topic = input("what is the topic of the question?")
    if question not in question_list:
        question_list.append(question)
    if topic not in topic_list:
        topic_list.append(topic)
    x -=1

def display_deck():
    top = Toplevel()
    for i in data: 
        if i == topic:
            button2 = Button(top, text=data[i], fg="black")
            button2.pack()

for topic, question in zip(topic_list, question_list):
    data[topic].append(question)

for y in topic_list:
    button = Button(root, text=y, fg="black", command=display_deck)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It asks the user 5 questions and then adds the button of the "topic" to the root window. When this topic button is clicked I want it to display just the questions in that topic. However currently it displays all the questions. I have tried using dictionaries but that didn't seem to work. Any help greatly appreciated.
([When I have clicked the maths button this is the Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKoSL.png))

**After Edit**

I think the downfall of the dictionary is using the zip method as not every item will be paired up in the list but I am really not sure. The output when using a dictionary and clicking the maths button is seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocoae.png)

Comment: The current code doesn't make any effort to separate the questions by topic. Can you show what you tried using dictionaries, since that's the natural approach?

Comment: @Blckknght I have added the dictionary I attempted to use to the code above ^

Comment: with `if topic not in topic_list:` you will have `topic_list` shorter than `question_list` and then `zip(topic_list, question_list)` will give incorrect results. Maybe add topic-question directly to `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `topic-question` directly to `data` and keep only `topic_list` to create buttons.

I send `topic` to function using `lambda` to assign to button function with argument.

Because `lambda` in `for-loop` can work strange so I use `arg=topic` instead of directly `display_deck(topic)`

```
import tkinter as tk
from collections import defaultdict

# --- functions ---

def display_deck(topic):
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    for question in data[topic]: 
        button = tk.Button(top, text=question)
        button.pack()

# --- main ---

topic_list = []
data = defaultdict(list)

# ask for 5 question-topic
for _ in range(5):
    question = input("what is your question?")
    topic = input("what is the topic of the question?")

    # keep topic to create buttons
    if topic not in topic_list:
        topic_list.append(topic)

    # add topic-question directly to data
    data[topic].append(question)

root = tk.Tk()

# create buttons 
for topic in topic_list:
    # assign function with argument
    button = tk.Button(root, text=topic, command=lambda arg=topic:display_deck(arg))
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```